# Using Qrio with rails. Works fine when i use it with ruby files, not working with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decode, chunkypng

I want to decode QR codes in my rails app. I am using Qrio gem which needs ChunkyPng gem to work. It is working fine when i write and run a ruby program using it. But, when i try using it with Rails it does not work.

This isthe error i get.

No such file or directory - chart.png

Extracted source (around line #5):
3
4
5
6
7
8

```
class PNGImageLoader
  def self.load(filename)
    image = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file(filename)

    bits = image.pixels.map do |pixel|
      grayscale = ChunkyPNG::Color.to_grayscale(pixel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the file you're trying to load doesn't exist. It seems to be looking for `chart.png` in your root directory. Make sure you use a full path and it will probably work.

Comment: I am supposed to load an image of the qr code but it is not working. I tried loading it from the assets folder, public folder. It dosent work yet.

Comment: Could you show us your code? If you using `Qrio::Qr.load(path_to_file)`, it should work. The above code still tells me the path to the file is wrong.

Comment: I was using paperclip to manage the uploads, while passing the file i used '@file.file.url', i should have used '@file.file.path' The path code worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you've found the problem!